# Is it normal that my rear bicycle wheel is 1/4 cm off to the left on the top of the seat stay and 1/2 cm off on the left of the chainstay?

Tags: wheels, rohloff

Allow me to elaborate. I have a Soma Wolverine type B with a Rohloff 500/14 speedhub and gates Carbon Drive (CDX) version. It’s not even broken in yet at 200 km. I had the bike custom built by a Rohloff distributor and bike builder in Toronto.
Everything is torqued perfectly and runs smooth like butter. However, I have noticed that the rear wheel is slightly off to the left when looking at the bicycle from the back. I took measurements and can confirm that the top of the wheel where it is close to the top of the seat stay is 1/4cm off to the left and at the bottom where the wheel is closest to the crankset on the chain stay the wheel is 1/2 cm off to the left. It is not at all affecting functionality. I’am running Ryde Andra disc rims with Renee Herse Oracle ridge tires 700/48c. Is the offset of the wheel in relation to the frame normal?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  It certainly doesn't sound right, but a few photos might help people analyse what's going on.

Comment: Hard to say- this is a good, well written question but definitely needs photos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you see something like this on a frame with sliding dropouts, the first inclination should be make sure the sliders are adjusted in line with each other. If there's any doubt, do it with dropout alignment tools. If they aren't, that's bad for any number of reasons, i.e. they should never be adjusted in a way that subjects the hub to dropout misalignment, especially a Rohloff. Make sure the threads and bolt shoulders are thoroughly greased (I like anti-seize for this but grease is fine).

In a perfect world, you can do what you need here by loosening both sliders, use the drive-side one to set the belt tension, and then tighten the left one exactly where it wants to land. In practice any friction impeding the NDS slider's ability to move freely could inhibit that, and also any squirm that occurs as you tighten the bolts, which proper lubrication of the bolts will help with. Typically I'd expect to hold the wheel in place while tightening the NDS slider at that point, but not have to do much to it to get it looking centered.

If the odd tire clearance against the stays can't be solved by adjusting the sliders properly, there becomes a murky element in that it doesn't say anything itself about the wheel's alignment with the center plane of the front triangle, nor about the presence or absence of stay length disparities, but that issue on bikes with non-asymmetric rear end designs does tend to indicate one of those things is going on. In other words, no it's not normal at that point, but it's not conclusive evidence of a problem. To know that conclusively you either need to be able to see the wheel being out of alignment with the seat tube, or you need framebuilder-level means of checking the dropout alignment against the front triangle. Hopefully it's not anything like that kind of problem, but it does bear thinking about because if one were to contrive scenarios where a stay length disparity from the factory was at its likeliest, you could do a lot worse than a small-production frame with sliders and a split stay.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I appreciate your astute level of knowledge! I also remember that when I bought the frame, the manufacturer’s manual suggested to measure the frame for any misalignments and correct them on a jig. This may also be a possibility.

Comment: *...or you need framebuilder-level means of checking the dropout alignment against the front triangle* - did you mean framebuilder-level as opposed to bike store-level? I ask because it's generally easier to find bike stores than framebuilders. Of course, the level of capacity and knowledge is going to vary by bike store, and this might depend on the higher-level mechanics

Comment: @WeiwenNg Checking dropout alignment against anything but each other implies framebuilder-type tooling, yes. Some shops have a table or jig around but it's uncommon.